# " web_browser & disown " : still see-ing data

Tags: bash, terminal, disown

terminal, run web browser:

```
  web_browser & disown
```

web browser opens fine.
it seems to be **disowned** by the terminal.

but as I use the web browser... to surf the web..

I begin to see the web browser reporting data
to that terminal.

terminal prints data about the web browser.

so I suppose "**disown**" is not sufficient to
**completely disown** the web browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web browser is still run with its output and input connected to your terminal.

Disown will only stop your shell from sending signals to it when it sends signals to its children.

To get rid of the output you need to redirect the output

```
browser  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or

```
browser  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

If you are running this in an ssh session you will also want to disconnect the input just in case so that it does not hang:

```
browser < /dev/null  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and then you can also disown it

```
browser < /dev/null  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
disown
```

Comment: In contrast `nohup` automatically redirects stdout and/or stderr from terminal to a file; the GNU version also redirects stdin to `/dev/null`

Comment: Because you got the redirection wrong, the questioner raised http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344368/ . (-:

Comment: Bah! I just fixed that too lol