# disown : unable to stop stderr s

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stderr, disown

**Problem:** 
Even with **dev null** and **disown**..
web browser is still reporting errors to the terminal
it launched from of.

```
  web_browser < /dev/null > /dev/null 1>&2 & disown
```

Comment: The incorrect redirection resulted from an incorrect answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344349/5132 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your redirections in disorder.

```
web_browser </dev/null 2>/dev/null 1>&2 & disown
```

What you did was first to redirect standard output to `/dev/null`, and then again to standard error.